# PhpStorm Xdebug Exiting Method Prematurely

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am working on an Ubuntu 18.04 system with PhpStorm version #PS-222.3345.135. I am on PHP 7.4.20 and Xdebug 2.9.8.

First off, when I am not running Xdebug on my web requests they work perfectly fine. When I attempt to step through execution with Xdebug, methods are exiting prematurely as I will show in the screenshots below:

First screenshot:

[image: Interceptor::launch()]

Execution is at the fist line of the `launch()` method. As such, pressing the Step Over button should bring execution to line 112 `($this->_state->setAreaCode($areaCode));` Instead, pressing Step Over prematurely exits the `launch()` method and brings the execution thread back out to the `Bootstrap::run()` method as shown below:

[image: After pressing Step Over]

Note that there is no `$response` variable in the `run()` local scope as the `launch()` method was not allowed to return a value due to being exited prematurely. Pressing Step Over again will result in an exception being thrown by the `$response->sendResponse()`, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Exception being thrown]

To summarize, the issue here is that Xdebug is not stepping through code correctly. This issue didn't start occurring until this past week, and my path mappings for the project are the same as they were before.

This is happening for multiple PhpStorm projects, not just this one codebase. However I do have one PhpStorm project (with a much smaller codebase) in which stepping through code works fine (I upgraded the PhpStorm memory limit to 2GB as a result but that did not resolve anything).

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: It's PhpStorm 2022.2 issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67891/Step-Over-broken-for-Xdebug-30-for-static-methods-and-private-properties-from-parent-classes#focus=Comments-27-6367485.0-0 Upgrade Xdebug to 3.1 -- can be enough. Or disable the new option (as per that comment/workaround in the ticker description). The issue is marked as fixed but some ppl still say it does not work for them when using 2022.2.1 Preview. If it's the same for you -- try making a code sample and submit it to that ticket. You may use 2022.1.4 until properly resolved.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you so much for this, was driving my crazy. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct. 

For anyone wondering, as per LazyOne's link above, disabling Preferences | PHP | Debug | Evaluation | Enable '__toString' object view worked for me as a workaround

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's PhpStorm 2022.2 issue ([WI-67891](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67891) ticket).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67891/Step-Over-broken-for-Xdebug-30-for-static-methods-and-private-properties-from-parent-classes#focus=Comments-27-6367485.0-0

> Reason of the bug is found and fixed. Fix will be available in next minor update. Below is a technical summary of the issue for ones who curious about what happened:
>
> 1. Xdebug had [a bug](https://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00001993) which is basically breaks further `step_over` commands by passing invalid `eval` commands. This bug is fixed in 3.1, but present in all older versions.
> 2. In 2022.2 We've implemented feature [WI-56517](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56517/Display-toString-representation-on-an-object-in-the-debug-Variables-pane-if-the-method-is-present) that shows `__toString` representation of the object in debug panel. This feature is implemented by passing `eval((string)expression)` command on start of debug sessions
> 3. It turned out that there are number of invalid inputs that happened to be produced by this command:
>
>    - Private properties from parent class. Xdebug returns such properties in the format that is not suitable for plain evaluation https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/5af18430eb0b2c9574e903e6a9b9ef40c0ea7296/src/lib/var_export_xml.c#L441
>    - `::` instead of `$this` in case of static method (issue [WI-67023](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67023/PHP-Debug-is-broken-in-static-class-methods))
>
> Combination of these factors resulted into broken `step_over`. Both cases are fixed and will be available in next minor update. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for reporting the issue.

The aforementioned [WI-67891](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67891) ticket is marked as fixed for 2022.2.1. You can [try 2022.2.1 Preview](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/08/phpstorm-2022-2-1-preview/) now.

At the same time there are some reports that there are still some scenarios (not-yet-covered cases) where the debug still does not work as in previous version. Sadly there are more rather useless "me too" comments than "here is a code sample where it is still does not work" (as it requires time to make it, to see what may be causing it, be able to spot the difference in setup/environment etc).

**Current solutions:**

- Upgrade to Xdebug 3.1 or newer if you can (the latest version right now is 3.1.5).
- Disable `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug | Evaluation | Enable '__toString' object view` until confirmed as properly resolved. Do not forget to revert it back (this feature seems convenient for a quick-glance when debugging).
- Stay on previous stable 2022.1.4 until the issue is confirmed as properly resolved.

Comment: I have the same issue still with version: 2022.2.3

Comment: @JosepAlsina Have you tried disabling `Enable '__toString' object view` option? If it's disabled and you having such an issue .. then it most likely be another issue.

Comment: Yeah, indeed I tried disabling it. Then it works more often.

Comment: @JosepAlsina if it's already disabled hen it's some another issue, possibly Xdebug itself. I suggest you make a ticket at the [PhpStorm Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) with some reproducible code sample + your environment (Xdebug/PHP versions, OS used, Docker/etc.), your `idea.log` file -- the info needed to reproduce the issue.